# Flutter installed but failed to start-up on real IOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, startup

Flutter failed to start-up on **real IOS device** (not emulator), its working fine on the IOS emulator but when I connect my device its installed but fails to launch without printing any message on flutter application log.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on XXXX in debug mode...

Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XXXXX
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        10.7s
Xcode build done.                                           20.1s
Installing and launching...
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.4-pre.262, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G3020, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

could you please help!

Comment: did you check your device version and the project version?

Comment: Can you add packages section in pubspec.yaml to see what libraries you are using, I had such an issue before and it was caused by misconfiguration regarding firebase services

Comment: Have you checked your app in device, I am facing same issue but the app is installed only app launch is failed, I don't know the exact cause for the problem though!

Comment: Hi @mariano-zorrilla 
project version: 1.0.0+1 and IOS version: 13.3.1

Comment: Hi @convict-moody I am not using firebase as I tried to create a new empty project to check if the problem was with the dependencies and I got the same issue.

Comment: Hi @yogesh-chawla
I am facing exactly the same issue, the app is installed successfully but the app failed to launch on my ISO device

Answer (score 1):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504#issuecomment-581554697) on Flutter repository as mentioned by @amer rawashdeh.

iOS 13.4 is now available, please update your iOS device and Xcode to v11.4 to keep your project newly working.

If you are on Flutter stable channel you need also to apply this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration) to keep you project working with v11.4 Xcode

Comment: In my case, the issue was fixed with the latest iOS 13.4.1. 
Thank you for your helpful information!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem with **ISO version 13.3.1** only
check it out: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504#issuecomment-581554697
The application was working on **IOS emulator version 13.3**